# CIfrado César, ¿alternar entre movimientos de la cadena?

Tags: c

Tengo que hacer una variante del Cifrado César que reciba el número de posiciones del desplazamiento k y que alterne entre los movimientos, la primer letra k posiciones hacia adelante, la segunda k hacia atrás y así sucesivamente hasta terminar la cadena de entrada.
Lo que tengo ahorita es esto, solamente no entiendo como hacer para que alterne entre los elementos de la cadena y vaya sumando y luego restando.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define MAX 128

void cifrar(char cadena[MAX], int k){

int i = 0;
while(cadena[i] != '\0'){
    cadena[i] = cadena[i] + k;
    i++;
}
printf("La cadena cifrada es: %s\n", cadena);
}

int main(){

char c[MAX];
int k;
printf("Introduce una cadena: ");
scanf("%128[^\n]", c);
printf("Introduce el número de posiciones de desplazamiento: ");
scanf("%d", &k);
cifrar(c,k);
}
```

Comment: si `i` es par sumar y si es impar restar, seria algo asi?

Answer (score 3):

> La primera letra `k` posiciones hacia adelante, la segunda `k` hacia atrás y así sucesivamente.

Pues es bastante sencillo, en la primera posición sumas `k`, en la segunda `-k` porque es bien sabido que sumar un número negativo es lo mismo que restarlo:

```
while(cadena[i] != '\0') {
    cadena[i] = cadena[i] + (i % 2 ? -k : k);
//                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ <-- Sumar o restar según se necesite
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Primero debes guardar tu cadena original en una variable temporal, para no perder información. También puedes usar una variable nueva para el resultado, necesitas:

```
#include <string.h>
```

Antes del ciclo debes hacer una copia

```
char cadenaOriginal[MAX];
strcpy(cadenaOriginal,cadena);
```

Para alternar debes usar una bandera que cambie de estado en cada ciclo, también puedes usar el modulo 2

```
if(i%2 == 0){
    //suma
}else{
    //resta
}
```

Es importante que sepas el tamaño de la cadena, para medir la cadena debes usar

```
int largo = strlen(cadena);
```

Con este **largo** puedes saber si el **indiceCifrado** esta fuera del rango y validar estas condiciones.

Suma

```
indiceCifrado = i+ k;
```

Resta

```
indiceCifrado = i- k;
```

Finalmente debes remplazar los valores originales en la nueva cadena cifrada.

```
if(nuevoIndice > -1 && nuevoIndice < largo)
    cadena[i] = cadenaOriginal[indiceCifrado];
```

Calcular el índice válido cuando se salga del rango te lo dejo a ti.